# set custom layout on every list item click

Tags: java, android, layout-inflater

I've made a listview. I want to replace the another layout textview on every on item click with some text.
onitemclicklistener method is

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View vv = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_show_quote_in_background, *,false);

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                TextView tv = vv.findViewById(R.id.showingquoteinbackground);
                tv.setText(motivationalQuote[i]);

                Toast.makeText(ShowQuote.this,i+" item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

What will I use in place of Viewgroup (in the place of *). So that I can replace another layout text.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot or layout file so get more precision in what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: your qus is not clear. what are you trying to achieve? Is this textview whose text you want to change exist in the same activity? If yes then why inflating it?

Just do TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.showingquoteinbackground);

Comment: the problem is how do i use the Layout Inflater in setonitemclicklistener method.

Comment: what will I use in the place of *